# SQLite3 randomly changes file permissions and owner

Tags: permissions, sqlite

I use sqlite3 for a PHP app. The functions I use are from the Sqlite3 package built in to PHP.

I do not normal CRUD actions, including restarting the DB for testing. This includes dropping tables and reinserting dummy data.

The DB file has file permissions of `sudo chmod a+rw` and `sudo chown $USER:www-data`.

This all works fine.

But at least once per day, I will get a no write error. And when I look at the DB, the permissions and ownership has changed.

The user and group changes to `$USER:$USER` and the file permissions change to `-rw-r--r--`

What could be causing this behavior?

OS: Debian 12

Comment: If the file is being updated, it would appear that $USER's default group is itself, not www-data. Perhaps your php script or something else is copying it. Your permissions are far to promiscuous, at the most, they should be -rw-rw-r--, and that is also how they should be set on the directory... if you have set the user up correctly. You do not want anyone & everyone having write permissions.

Comment: What is the right user setup?

Answer (score 0):

When sqlite3 operates on a database, it makes a copy, updates the copy, and then deletes the original and renames the copy to the original.

When this happens, the permissions are reset to defaults.  You can change the defaults this way:

- To set the default group, change the group of the parent directory and make the group sticky with `sudo chmod g+s .`  (or replace `.` with the name of the parent directory if you aren't there).  This will cause all files created in that directory to inherit the directory's group.
- To set the default group write permissions, change the umask.  You probably want umask 000 or umask 002 (it is probably currently 022).  This probably needs to be done at the beginning the php process (or before it is started).

Comment: on a system with ACLs, you could also set the default ACL on the directory holding the file, it should override the umask setting of the process

Comment: Does this mean I need to use umask before and after every database transaction?

Comment: @Vinn Either have the Bourne shell set `umask 0` before the php interpreter begins running, or use [umask(0)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) within your php script.

Comment: That's wrong. I just checked, when I updated an sqlite3 db, the inode number stayed the same. Even if it did do copy & update, it would require write permissions to the directory. And again, even if it did, sqlite3 should be smart enough to preserve the permissions.

Comment: I can't see how the permissions would get reset unless the file is getting replaced.  I think it doesn't always replace it, but not sure.  Also, what makes you think the inode number would change just because the file was deleted and recreated?  I don't think that's guaranteed to happen.

Comment: @Bib - you are telling us what is wrong, but not what is right. The permissions are still changing, do you have a suggestion as to why?

Comment: Actually, I'm 100% sure if you tell sqlite3 to compress the database that it will copy it and delete the original as I've described.  Other actions may also trigger this.  So @bib is just wrong and did not "check" well.  And apparently unfortunately it isn't smart enough to preserve permissions.

Comment: @user10489 Where does compression come into this? This is the first time anyone has mentioned it. Compression is also optional. All you are doing it modifying your argument to support your theory. I am correct, by default, SQLite3 does not do copy & update. And what are these other actions?

Comment: You implied sqlite3 never does this.  Compression or compaction or vaccum, whatever you want to call it triggers this.  It's both a sqlite command and a setting that can automatically trigger it.  It's in the API, thus any program using the database can trigger it.  It's at least one example of how this can happen.  And yes, sqlite3 requires a writable database to be in a writable directory, just to open the database.

Comment: And you implied that it always does. In the default config, it never does. As I suggested, it may be an external command changing the perms, such as logrotate.